# Why writing map entries to a HashSet is slower than to a CopyOnWriteArraySet in Java

Tags: java, set, benchmarking, hashset

I think writing to a `HashSet` will be faster than to a `CopyOnWriteArraySet`; I'm not doing multi threading here. However I surpisingly got benchmark results indicate writing map entries to a CopyOnWriteArraySet is faster.

I did benchmarking on writing 1000 of Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> into a HashSet vs CopyOnWriteArraySet.

```
Benchmark          (n)   Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
A.writeToCOWAS    1000  thrpt    4  1269.214 ± 40.635  ops/s
A.writeToHashSet  1000  thrpt    4   223.118 ± 34.955  ops/s
```

In addition to that, I got benchmark results of equals() and hashCode() of `Map.Entry` reveal that the former is more expensive.

```
Benchmark           Mode  Cnt          Score          Error  Units
MapEntry.equals    thrpt    4  177773394.054 ± 75436098.388  ops/s
MapEntry.hashCode  thrpt    4  272240403.923 ± 38794396.671  ops/s
```

I believe writing to a HashSet calls to hashCode() while CopyOnWriteArraySet calls to equals().

In the case of writing Integer or String,HashSet is way faster. Then I'm wondering what happens with `Map.Entry` type and why CopyOnWriteArraySet is faster according to my analysis?

My perf test:

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(value = 2)
@Warmup(iterations = 2, time = 3)
@Measurement(iterations = 2, time = 3)
public class A {
    public Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> set;

    @Param({"1000"})
    public int n;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        set = new HashSet<>((int) (n / 0.75f + 1f), 0.75f);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            set.add(Map.entry(i, i));
    }

    private void eliminateDeadCode(Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> out, Blackhole hole) {
        int hash = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> o : out)
            hash += o.hashCode();
        hole.consume(hash);
        if (out.size() != set.size())
            throw new RuntimeException(out.size() + " != " + set.size());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void writeToCOWAS(Blackhole hole) {
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> out = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>(set);
        eliminateDeadCode(out, hole);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void writeToHashSet(Blackhole hole) {
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> out = new HashSet<>(set);
        eliminateDeadCode(out, hole);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(A.class.getSimpleName())
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: This will depend on lots of things, like the size, capacity or load factor of your collections, the quality of the hashes (frequency of collisions and distribution), and complexity of the hashcode and equals methods etc.

Comment: I've just attached my benchmark code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hulk's answer is very instructive. However the problem is not necessarily the `Map.entry()` hashCode implementation, which is this, at least in Java 11:

```java
public int hashCode() {
    return key.hashCode() ^ value.hashCode();
}
```

The problem is that the hash codes of key and value are always the same, both in the OP's test, and in Hulk's test, hence the hash codes combined via XOR will always end up as 0. Change it so that key and value are different, and performance will change.

Comment: Wow, I wonder if this ever happens in real-world code.  A cheap way to avoid it might be to add the two inputs instead of XOR, at the risk of maybe losing some entropy in the low bits which is where you most want it for a hash function.  But if they're identical, `x+x` is just `x<<1`, while `x^x` is 0.

Comment: @PeterCordes `key.hashCode() == value.hashCode()` hints at redundant information, i.e. waste of memory. Does it occur in the real world? When trading memory space for performance perhaps...

Comment: Yeah, it's redundant, but some code is written without care for efficiency.  And it might even have non-stupid use cases, like as a default initializer for a data structure which will later be modified.  Or for storing a map which happens to be the identity map for most elements.  If from user input, this opens up a possible denial of service by sending an input that will trigger surprising worst-case performance.  Many VMs choose sorting algorithms with an eye towards defending against malicious worst-case inputs.

Comment: Wow, interesting - updated my answer to reflect your findings.

Comment: @PeterCordes How about `x == y ? x : (x ^ y)`?

Comment: That's slower (in all cases) for negligible benefit vs. always using `x+y`.  If there is correlation but not exact equality between hash codes, `+` is still safer than `^` in terms of keeping more entropy, I  think.  And if they're both uniformly randomly distributed, the `x+y` and `x^y` are both uniformly randomly distributed.  Including the low bit, which is the same for both cases.  Possibly there's some argument for why xor is better than binary addition in the non-correlated case, but if there's any possibility of correlation, I think just add is plenty good.

Comment: I seem to recall reading that Linux's random pool used `+` for mixing in possibly-correlated sources of randomness (like the time when an interrupt arrived), or at least avoided plain `^` to avoid cancellation, because it's a bad mixing function for that use-case.  But I couldn't find confirmation of that now; search results are full of discussion of whether it XORs in rdrand / rdseed HW rng values, and where.

Comment: I'm assuming that `hash(k) = -hash(v)` is no more likely than any other 32-bit value.  With a good hash function, which most standard objects have, even k = -v won't cause that.

Comment: And I'm assuming that producing `x+x` as a hash code is fine for most applications; if having the low bit always 0 is a problem, like leaving half the hash buckets unused, that would be something to reconsider.  Like maybe `(x+(long)y)>>1` to shift the 33-bit sum back down to 32 bits? (Most 32-bit ISAs can do that fairly cheaply with add/rcr.  But xor/cmovz to implement your way is cheaper on modern x86.  Instead of a separate compare, you just compute the XOR and use the FLAGS to see if it was zero.  It does introduce non-uniformity; the hash code is less likely to be zero.)

Comment: `(x+(long)y)>>1` probably isn't ideal, either.  That's the average of unsigned 32-bit numbers, so it's not uniform in its highest bit; only set if there was carry-out from the high bit.  `x+y` would perform as fast for existing cases, and be good in all bits except the lowest even in the worst case (this one), even if it only used half the buckets of a hash table, it's still only a factor of 2 worst-case badness instead of a factor of N.  And with no performance or machine-code size regression for the good case, with uncorrelated object hashes.

Answer (score 5):

One essential aspect of HashMap/Set performance is the quality of the hashcode distribution, because bad distributions can lead to the map degrading to just a few large buckets, which leaves us with the bookkeeping overhead without getting any of the benefits.

It seems that the `Map.Entry` implementation returned by [Map.entry()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) uses an implementation that always yields `0` when the hashcodes of key and value are equal, at least in the implementation I'm currently using (see [Evgeniy Berezovsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73188382/2513200) for details).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1000;
    HashSet<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> set = new HashSet<>((int) (n / 0.75f + 1f), 0.75f);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        set.add(Map.entry(i, i));
    
    set.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.hashCode()));         
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
...
```

This yields **worst-case performance** for any hash-based collection.

---

This is probably less of a problem when using it for the purpose it was designed for, i.e. (from the javaDocs):

> These entries are suitable for populating Map instances using the Map.ofEntries() method.

because the Nodes and Map itself only use the hashcode of the keys and values, not that of the entries, but it is a problem when using them as keys themselves.